# Why this function javascript not alert?

Tags: javascript

Why this function javascript not alert ?

First , Click `CLICK 1` it's will show `delete` and then click `delete`

Why not alert `111-aaaa` How can i do that?

https://jsfiddle.net/tdpusq05/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="test_fn1()">CLICK 1</div>
<div id="demo"></div>

<script>
function test_fn1() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<span onclick='delete_fn('111-aaaa')'>delete</span>";
};
</script>

<script>
function delete_fn(no_delete)
{
    alert(no_delete);
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove single quotes from `onclick` around `delete_fn('111-aaaa')` like following

```
function test_fn1() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<span onclick=delete_fn('111-aaaa')>delete</span>";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

change the `test_fn1` method to escape the quotes, here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/o8d82edv/2/)

```
function test_fn1() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<span onclick=\"delete_fn('111-aaaa')\">delete</span>";
}

function delete_fn(no_delete)
{
    alert(no_delete);
}
```

Comment: @mongmongseesee check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/o8d82edv/2/ it is working

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div onclick="test_fn1()">CLICK 1</div>
<div id="demo"></div>

<script>
    function test_fn1() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<span onclick='delete_fn(\"111-aaaa\")'>delete</span>";
    }
</script>

<script>
    function delete_fn(no_delete) {
        alert(no_delete);
    };
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @mongmong seesee plz check this :)

Answer (score 0):

JS will not catch dynamically created elements by using onclick function.
you have to do [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) (if you are using **jQuery**) :-

```
$('#id').on('click', 'yourSelector', function() {
  //do something
});
```

Comment: OP's question has nothing to do with jquery